# Getting resulting data from website query

Tags: php, url

I need to get the resulting data from a website query. for example

http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=organism:9606+AND+gene:AEBP1+AND+reviewed:yes&sort=score&format=tab&columns=entry%20name

resulting page shows

Entry name

AEBP1_HUMAN

I need the result, in this case "AEBP1_HUMAN" to be display on my website. Confused how to get it. Thanks

Comment: $_GET['query'] and then do whatever you need to the query string.

Comment: 'AEBP1_HUMAN' is nowhere in that query string

Comment: Your question is not clear! please try adding some more informations **+1**

Comment: The page he requests returns the "AEBP1_HUMAN"..... See my answer to find functions to handle the return of the text

Answer (score 0):

The goal is, that you can read the content of any url like a file, because php supports wrappers for variety of protocols.

First example uses function [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php%20file) that read entire content and split it by lines into an array.

```
<?php
$content = file($url);
echo $content[1];
?>
```

In the second example you get the whole content as a string, so you have to split it with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function by line endings.

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
echo $lines[1];
?>
```

Third example uses standard file open in combination with function fgets that read the content line by line.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen($url);
$fp = fopen($url, 'r');
$line = fgets($fp);
$line = fgets($fp);
echo $line;
?>
```

The last example shows usage of curl. Don't forget to use right options.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

$lines = explode("\n", $content);
echo $lines[1];
?>
```

Sometimes you may experience problems on public hosting servers, where reading remote content is blocked.

Comment: Rather than just spitting code out on a page it's advantageous to all if you can add (even a small) explanation with each code of what it does.

Comment: A have considered the code too simple. But you are right, I have  mentioned some differences.

Comment: Thanks to all for helping, the codes by Ondřej were very useful. I just had to also correctly send the gene symbol to URL. Here is what I used finally:    $url='http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=organism:9606+AND+gene:'.$gene_symbol.'+AND+reviewed:yes&sort=score&format=tab&columns=entry%20name';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
echo $lines[1];